# SSL Configuration in Spring Boot and SSL Configuration in Apache Server

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, mod-jk

I need your help to gain some clarity over running spring boot applications on SSL protocol. So far I have an understanding that SSL configuration is only needed to server's end, until I recently discovered that to run a spring boot application on SLL, we need to do configuration in spring boot app's properties file.

Below is how my server is configured. I need to know if I still need to do any configuration in my spring boot application.properties file?

My Apache Server runs on SSL protocol. Any connections to port 80 are redirected to 443 port by Apache. My Tomcat running is on port 8080. I have a reverse proxy configured using mod_jk module. So basically the user only interacts with my Apache server on SSL and Apache in turn talks to Tomcat in the background.

Comment: I suggest that you use list rather than board of text when possible. It is really hard to read....

Comment: I’m afraid, I didn’t quite understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure both Tomcat and the JVM to use the same trust store, and also configure Tomcat to have a keystore for outbound requests.

For Tomcat, you can add the following to your application.properties to set the keystore and truststore:

```
server.ssl.key-store=file:/path/to/keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=<password>
server.ssl.key-alias=<key_alias>
server.ssl.trust-store=file:/path/to/truststore.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=<password>
```

For the JVM, you can use -D arguments, system properties, etc:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/truststore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<password>
```

Note this will use the default port for Tomcat. You can override this in application.properties:

```
server.port=8443
```

Also note that there is no AJP connector started by default with embedded Tomcat. You can use [this](https://blog.swdev.ed.ac.uk/2015/06/24/adding-embedded-tomcat-ajp-support-to-a-spring-boot-application/) blog to see how to set one up.